# MongoExport from remote server

Tags: mongoexport

I am able connect Mongo Atlas from remote server by using below command---

```
mongo mongodb+srv://User_Name:Password@Vivek-dev-tze.gcp.mongodb.net/test
```

Now I have to export particular collections data in file and I and using below command but I getting error.

```
mongoexport --uri "mongodb+srv://User_Name:Password@Vivek-dev-tze.gcp.mongodb.net/DB" --collection xyz --out xyz.json
```

Output - Failed:

> error running `listCollections`. Database: `DB` Err: not authorized
>   on DB to execute command { listCollections: 1, filter: { name: "xyz"
>   }, cursor: {}, $db: "DB" }

```
mongoexport --host="mongodb+srv://User_Name:Password@Vivek-dev-tze.gcp.mongodb.net:27017" --collection=xyz --db=DB --out=xyz.json
```

Output -

> error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

I have to export particular MongoDB collections data in file

Command 1- `mongoexport --uri "mongodb+srv://User_Name:Password@Vivek-dev-tze.gcp.mongodb.net/DB" --collection xyz --out xyz.json`

Output -

> Failed: error running `listCollections`. Database: `DB` Err: not
>   authorized on DB to execute command { listCollections: 1, filter: {
>   name: "xyz" }, cursor: {}, $db: "DB" }

Command 2- `mongoexport --host="mongodb+srv://User_Name:Password@Vivek-dev-tze.gcp.mongodb.net:27017" --collection=xyz --db=DB --out=xyz.json`

Output -

> error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Command 1 -

> Failed: error running `listCollections`. Database: `DB` Err: not
>   authorized on DB to execute command { listCollections: 1, filter: {
>   name: "xyz" }, cursor: {}, $db: "DB" }

Command 2 -

> error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Answer (score 1):

I experimented the same error. Seems that mongodb at 26-11-2019 does not work with the uri starting with `--uri "mongodb+srv...` and `--host="mongodb+srv:...`

The correct way to do it, is using the following command:

```
mongoexport --host <DATABASE_SHARDS> --ssl --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD> --authenticationDatabase admin --db <DATABASE> --collection <COLLECTION> --type <FILETYPE> --out <FILENAME>
```

If you are using MongoDB cloud, the command can be found in the Command Line Tools tab.